# History of Employment when applying for Canadian study permit

Tags: visa, immigration, canada, student-visa, students

In the "Employment" section of the Application for a Study Permit Outside of Canada (IMM 1294), the following question is asked and it's mandatory to fill out the duration, current activity/occupation, city, country and company/employer for at least one field.

> Give details of your employment for the past 10 years, including if you have held any government positions (such as civil servant, judge, police officer, mayor, member of parliament, hospital administrator.)

Now, I'm a secondary school student and have no history in employment whatsoever, but the online form does not allow me to leave it blank or write N/A. In other words, I cannot "validate" the online form with my electronic signature and submit it without filling this information in. However, I don't have any dates or info to fill it in with, so what should I do?

Comment: Put Not Applicable N/A in the title/details and put your birth date to current date as the date and explain in an optional letter of explanation why you don't have any employment history (because you never worked).

Answer (score 1):

Put Not Applicable N/A in the title/details and put your birth date to current date as the date and explain in an optional letter of explanation why you don't have any employment history (because you never worked).